# Safely pruning merged topic branches locally

Tags: bash, git

## Background

My team develops in a git [monorepo](https://medium.com/@maoberlehner/monorepos-in-the-wild-33c6eb246cb9). User stories are broken into very small discrete sub-tasks and merged directly into `master`, rather than into a feature branch for the story.

#### Topic branches

Our topic branch names are all of the form `issue/<developer username>/<subtask ticket>`.

Those are pushed to *origin* and merged via a code-reviewed pull-request process.

#### Release branches

We also maintain long-lived release branches named `release/sprint/<number>` used for hot-patching.

Release branches are never re-merged to `master`. The individual fixes, if relevant in the current release, are re-implemented in another branch or applied as a [patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory). There are few enough of them to manage manually.

## Work

This works well for us, but it means we have hundreds of topic branches hanging around as developers often forget to delete them as they go.

I wrote a simple bash script to

1. Sync up with *origin* (we have only one),
2. Figure out which branches have been merged into `master` (or, optionally, a different branch, so far nobody has used that),
3. Delete locally-merged branches,
4. Optionally run the *gc*

The verbose prompting at every stage is intentional [as reassurance](https://youtu.be/31XZYMjg93o?list=PL0lo9MOBetEGRAJzoTCdco_fOKDfhqaOY).

## Concerns

Primarily, is this "safe", meaning:

1. Have I used an appropriate method to list branches?
2. Have I used an appropriate method for deleting branches?
3. Have I accounted for all possible pathways that could result in destruction of a local branch?
4. Have I adequately guarded against destruction of a local branch not merged into `master`?
5. Should I verify that topic branches have been merged into *origin*'s `master` and not the local `master`, in the event that a user mistakenly merges locally and loses their branch?

I'm very happy for any additional comments, no matter how nit-picky.

## Code

```
#!/bin/bash
MERGED_INTO=${1:-"master"}

statistics() {
  echo
  echo "Remaining local branches:"
  git branch

  echo
  echo "These local branches are not merged into ${MERGED_INTO}:"
  git branch --no-merged ${MERGED_INTO}

  echo
  echo "Size of local repo: $(git count-objects)"

  git status
}

error () {
  echo "WARNING: Something went wrong. Aborting..."
  if [[ ${1} ]]; then echo "The previous command exited with ${?}"; fi

  echo "This is the current state of your working copy:"
  git status
}

confirm () {
  read -r -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " response
  case ${response} in
    [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
      true
      ;;
    *)
     echo "Ok, aborting..."
     echo
     false
     ;;
  esac
}

check_on_main_branch() {
  local current_branch;
  current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)
  if [ "${current_branch}" != "${MERGED_INTO}" ]; then
    echo "You should be on '${MERGED_INTO}' for this operation. I can switch branches for you."
    confirm && git checkout "${MERGED_INTO}" || error $?
  fi
}

delete_local_merged_branches() {
  git branch --merged ${MERGED_INTO} | egrep -v "(^\*|${MERGED_INTO})" | xargs git branch --delete
}

# Step 1
echo "Fetching remote branch state"
git fetch --all

# Step 2
echo "The following local branches have been merged into ${MERGED_INTO} and will be deleted locally:"
git branch --merged ${MERGED_INTO} | egrep -v "(^\*|${MERGED_INTO})"
confirm && delete_local_merged_branches

# Step 3
echo "Would you like to run the garbage collector?"
confirm && \
 echo "Before garbage collecting: $(git count-objects)" && \
 git gc

trap statistics EXIT
trap error SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final line has no effect:

```
trap error SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
```

As the program is about to exit, we're *exceedingly* unlikely to receive any of those signals between this point and the end of the program.

It's much more usual to set the trap handler as soon as you've defined the `error` function.

Similarly, the exit trap

```
trap statistics EXIT
```

is the same as simply

```
statistics
```

when we're about to exit.  I suggest that this line is moved to before Step 1, too.

Comment: Many [references](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/) I've encountered explaining `trap` tend to show them at the end of a script. I did not realize they were only registered when they were encountered (though, saying that aloud I do feel rather inane). Useful information!

Comment: Look carefully at the examples you linked - some of those are just partial scripts; in the others, the traps are registered after defining the functions but before using them.

Answer (score 3):

#### Previous exit code

This will only ever print 0 exit code:

> ```
> if [[ ${1} ]]; then echo "The previous command exited with ${?}"; fi
> ```

Because the last exit code at the time of the `echo` will be the result of the `[[` builtin. Since `$1` in this function has the intended exit code to report, you should use just that.

#### Exit code of a function

Although this works:

> ```
> confirm () {
>   read -r -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " response
>   case ${response} in
>     [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
>       true
>       ;;
>     *)
>      echo "Ok, aborting..."
>      echo
>      false
>      ;;
>   esac
> }
> ```

It would be better to write `return 0` instead of `true` and `return 1` instead of `false`, to return from the function. The current `true` / `false` solution only works because they are the last statement in their execution paths. If later you accidentally add some code after `esac`, that will break the function. If you want to return from a function, just use the `return` statement.

#### Redundant semicolon

The semicolon here is redundant:

> ```
> local current_branch;
> ```

Comment: "_You need to save the original exit code in a variable_". That's not strictly necessary because`$1` already holds the desired value, so OP only needs to put `$1` instead of `$?` in that `echo` statement.